# How can I display data into my Jtextarea from my data base Mysql

Tags: mysql, jtextarea

I have problem when I try to display data(the result of a query) from my database mysql to my jTextarea, when I compile I have an error exception like:

```
SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate()
```

I have used a "select" query from my table where the name is the name written in my jTextFieldNom,this is my code, I hope that some one help me because I don't know how to resolve the problem, I 'm sure that my query is correct but I don't know where is the problem.

```
String pilote = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
jComboBoxType.addItemListener(new ItemState());
jComboBoxMenaces.addItemListener(new ItemState());
try {
    Class.forName(pilote); 
    Connection connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root"," "); 

    Statement instruction = connexion.createStatement(); 
    String a=jTextFieldNom.getText();


    String SQL = "select description from table where nomcol="+a+";"; 
    ResultSet rs = instruction.executeQuery(SQL);
    instruction = connexion.createStatement();


    int rowsEffected = instruction.executeUpdate(SQL);
    jTextArea1.append(rs.getString("description"));                                     
}
...... //bloc catch
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is executing a Select statement which is throwing the error.

```
int rowsEffected = instruction.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

You don't need this line because you aren't updating your database.

Also change the append to setText

```
jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("description"));
```

Try this:

```
String pilote = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
jComboBoxType.addItemListener(new ItemState());
jComboBoxMenaces.addItemListener(new ItemState());
try {
    Class.forName(pilote); 
    Connection connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root"," "); 

    Statement instruction = connexion.createStatement(); 
    String a=jTextFieldNom.getText();


    String SQL = "select description from table where nomcol="+a+";"; 
    ResultSet rs = instruction.executeQuery(SQL);

    jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("description"));                                     
}
```

Comment: thanks eabraham for your answer but I have another problem,when i modified m code as you tell me,I have an other exception SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'windows.exe' in 'where clause' ,I don't know why

Comment: Please post the 'table' table details.  I need to know more about the table you are querying.

Comment: No, I need the sql for the create table. 

CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    [table_options]
    [partition_options]
 etc.

Comment: ok,
my table should has a list of processes,it has the columns:

     id_proc ->integer:to indicate the process id,
     nomcol->varchar:contains the name of each process like windows.exe or bit.exe...,
     type_p -> varchar:for the type of the process,
     descproc ->varchar:to describe the process ,
     and thanks for help

Comment: create table process(id_proc int(3) primary key,nomcol varchar(10),type_p varchar(10),descproc varchar(30)); the query works when I executed in the MySQL Command line prompt but in my java code no thanks again

Comment: Change your sql to "select descproc from table where nomcol="+a+";" and java to jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString("descproc"));

Comment: hello sir again,I have an always the same exeption: SQL Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'proc.exe' in 'where clause' this process is in the data base,but I don't know why his description is displayed in the textarea

Comment: Add single quotes around the variable.  Like this : "select descproc from table where nomcol='"+a+"';"